# Boundary Properties of Converging Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

Just something that's been in my head for a while:

If $a_n$ is a sequence of positive real numbers for $n\in{1,2,...,N}$ and it is known that
$$
S_\epsilon(N)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{a_k}{k^{1+\epsilon}}
$$
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} S_\epsilon(N) < \infty
$$
for all $\epsilon>0$ and $S_0(N)=\infty$, is there anything more we can gain from this information other than
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_k}{k^{1+\epsilon}}=0 ?
$$

It just seems like there's more information to be gained, but it seems like even making the statement
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}=0
$$

isn't necessarily the case, but am I mistaken?  It seems like we know something more about the boundary of $\epsilon$ parameter.

Comment: Do you mean for these sums to be infinite series? How can $S_0(N)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{a_k}{k} = \infty$ when there are finitely many summands?

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I mis-typed. I'll fix.

Comment: Since the $a_k$ are positive, I recommend simply writing infinite series instead of limits. It is true that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{a_k}k = 0$ can be false: take $a_k = k$ if $k$ is a power of $2$ and $a_k=0$ (or reallyreally small if you must have strict positivity) otherwise.